# Problem with importing users to Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, cryptography

I have recently been migrating my app to firebase, but I am facing a problem with migrating my users to Firebase Auth.

In my old backend written using NodeJS, I used the following code to generate a password hash for a user:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var sha256 = crypto.createHmac("sha256", "MY-SECRET");

var hash = sha256.update(str).digest('hex');
```

Following [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-import), I have tried running this command to import my users:

```
firebase auth:import "my_users.csv" --hash-algo "HMAC_SHA256" --hash-key "my-secret-in-base64" --project "my_project"
```

my_users.csv:

```
random_uid,test_user@gmail.com,,their_hash_created_with_my_program
```

The command says that it imported the users successfuly, but when I try and log into an account using `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, it gives me an `auth/wrong-password` error.

I am new to Firebase and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated Answer:

I modified your code a little but and tested it out locally using a made up user with an email of `test@example.com` and a password of `password`. Hopefully you can reproduce logging in by running this quick test and then modify it to work with your hash values. The secret I am using is `MY-SECRET`.

```
var str = 'password'; // password used for testing
var mySecret = 'MY-SECRET'; // secret used for testing

var crypto = require('crypto');
var sha256 = crypto.createHmac("sha256", mySecret);

var hash = sha256.update(str).digest('hex');

var base64String = Buffer.from(hash, 'hex').toString('base64');

var secret64String = Buffer.from(mySecret).toString('base64');

console.log('hexhash: %s\nbase64StrHash: %s\nsecret base64: %s', hash, base64String, secret64String);

// This outputs the following:
// hexhash: 67f8b4aed3b3c353fcb1fbb7f2efaaafe15e08239eaebfdbe61e72b40a737d08
// base64StrHash: Z/i0rtOzw1P8sfu38u+qr+FeCCOerr/b5h5ytApzfQg=
// secret base64: TVktU0VDUkVU
```

I then ran the following command:

```
firebase auth:import "users.csv" --hash-algo "HMAC_SHA256" --hash-key "TVktU0VDUkVU" --project "mytestproject"
```

My csv:

```
0123456789,test@example.com,,Z/i0rtOzw1P8sfu38u+qr+FeCCOerr/b5h5ytApzfQg=, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

Using these exact values as input for my csv and for my encoding worked for me. If this is not working for you, it may be something else with how you originally coded your hashing such as adding a salt or some other values to the password before hashing. I would first try to validate that the base64 strings that you are supplying are working correctly with a small test case and move forward from there. If the csv file and command I provided do not work with your project, it may be that your client is not connected to Firebase Auth (I sometimes forget to connect to Firebase on setting up a new client applicaton).

Original Answer:
Reading the documentation, I think instead of digest("hex") you would want digest('base64') as the hash-key value in the csv as it needs to be a base64 encoded string.

Comment: So do you suggest that I convert my hashes to UTF-8, and then to Base64?

Comment: No, I believe you can do it directly from this command : car hash = sha256.update(str).digest('base64').

Comment: But how will I migrate the users that have had their password hashed with digest('hex')?

Comment: UPDATE: I have converted all of the password hashes to base64 as if they were generated with digest('base64'), but it still doesn't work

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to look in a little bit as I am boarding a plane. I was convinced when I viewed the sample that it was because a base64 value was expected but a hex value was supplied. Might be something else going on

Comment: Sorry, one last question. Have you tried converting your existing password hash vales (which are currently hex) using something like this : var base64String = Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex').toString('base64')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248965/discussion-between-jptr21824-and-alexander-n).